# Marrying a woman

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is it possible in English to describe a woman who married a man as follows:
She is under him.
Thank You.

Comment: If you don't explain, and clarify, your question will be put on hold.Are you talking about the superiority of the husband over a wife? Or are you speaking about the traditional roles? In any case, today, if you said a "wife is under a husband" you'll probably raise a few giggles (missionary position)  or get your head bitten off.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not a metaphor in American (or to my knowledge any) English.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean that his social status is more respected than hers then there are a variety of (snobbish and rarely-used-today) phrases.  The most formal of these is to say either that

***he married beneath himself / his station***

or that

***she married above herself / her station***,

depending on which of them was the prime mover!

Comment: Dear Admin, I am committed to writing good questions and at the same time I get answers from friend. Could you tell me exactly what is wrong?

Comment: @Mogahed - the problem with your question is that there is very little context.  Can you explain/illustrate what you are wanting to communicate with the phrase "She is under him"?

Comment: What I mean to say is that: Does this sentence "She is under him." means "She is married to him."?

Comment: @Mogahed "She is under him" does not mean she is married to him.